# How to get JSON text to HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, web

How Can I add these JSON values to text field in HTML.
JSON:

```
"data": [
{
  "zamestnanci": "3",
  "konvoje": "0",
  "pozice": "1533",
  "kilometry":  "5445"
}]}
```

I need add these 4 values to these 4 text fields:

```
<div class="counter-item">
    <h2>here value 1</h2>
    <h6>Odjeté konvoje</h6>
</div>
<div class="counter-item">
    <h2>here value 2</h2>
    <h6>Odjeté konvoje</h6>
</div>
<div class="counter-item">
    <h2>here value 3</h2>
    <h6>Pozice</h6>
</div>
<div class="counter-item">
    <h2>here value 4</h2>
    <h6>Najeté kilometry</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) you haven't got any text fields, just some static HTML. Of course you can over-write some of the HTML content, but still they are not _fields_ technically. 2) What have you done so far to research and try this? You could find hundreds of previous questions, tutorials, examples etc online which would show you the basics of this idea. You are not the first person to ask. And we are not really in the business of repeating ourselves. It's not a free do-my-work-for-me service. We'll _help_ you with a specific problem in your code, not just provide a whole solution for free.

Comment: This is not a free freelance platform. You should try to do something by yourself. If you encountered a problem, write down your code so we can identify a bug/problem and help you.

Comment: Also note that the keys in the object are not really ordered. Using `Object.values()` happens to return the values in the order provided here, but that's not really a reliable way to store data that is supposed to be a list.

Comment: There's no correlation between your json and your html.  Html has 2x 'Odjete konvoje' and the others that are unique only partially match the json "keys".

Comment: I have already searching on internet And I have an idea, but @Purab solved my problem thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to select `h2` child in class `counter-item`, and assign value to it.

Please refer below CodingGround URL: 
http://tpcg.io/MFiJda